# AttributeError in my python code 2

Tags: python

I have the following line of codes in python:

```
class BankAccount:
  def __init__ (self,balance = 0):
    self.balance = balance

    def deposit(self, deposit_amount= 30):
      self.deposit_amount=deposit_amount
      balance += deposit_amount
      return balance

      def withdraw (self,withdraw_amount= 10):
        if withdraw_amount > balance:
          raise RuntimeError('Invalid Transaction')
          balance -= withdraw_amount
          return balance

          class MinimumBalanceAccount(BankAccount):
            def __init__(self,balance = 0):
              self.balance = balance

              c = BankAccount()
              c.deposit(50)
```

it gives me this error:

```
AttributeError("BankAccount instance has no attribute 'deposit'"
```

Comment: You've got some indentation and formatting problems

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place. Can you correct it please to match your actual code?

Comment: Unrelated but important: In Python 2, _always_ derive top-level classes from `object`: I.e., define it like this: `class BankAccount(object): ...`. If you don't, you will not see all the documented behavior of objects and classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your indentation is actually as you posted it, then the `deposit` function is defined within the `__init__` method. As such, it's not an attribute to the class, but a mere function available within the `__init__` method. The following code is simply a copy of your code, but with indentation fixed:

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self,balance=0):
        self.balance = balance

    def deposit(self, deposit_amount=30):
        self.deposit_amount=deposit_amount
        self.balance += deposit_amount
        return self.balance

    def withdraw(self,withdraw_amount=10):
        if withdraw_amount > self.balance:
            raise RuntimeError('Invalid Transaction')
        self.balance -= withdraw_amount
        return self.balance

class MinimumBalanceAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self,balance = 0):
        self.balance = balance

c = BankAccount()
c.deposit(50)
```

This code works for me, as it does when I replace `c = BankAccount()` with `c = MinimumBalanceAccount()`

Comment: kindly help correct this error in line 16                                                                 line 16, in BankAccount
    class MinimumBalanceAccount(BankAccount):
NameError: name 'BankAccount' is not defined

Comment: As long as the class definition of BankAccount has been completed, `BankAccount` should be defined. I'm guessing you're trying to instantiate (`BankAccount()`) within the definition of BankAccount itself, but I can't tell without seeing code. Also keep in mind that in the code you posted above, MinimumBalanceAccount inherits from BankAccount, but you over-wrote the `__init__` method. If you want it to still be initialized like a regular BankAccount, call `BankAccount.__init__(self, balance)` within MinimumBalanceAccount's `__init__`

Comment: the code is the one I posted initially(atop the page) kindly help